# React Native Debugger: how to enable auto inspect elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

How do you enable the RN debugger to automatically go to the specific element you just clicked on or navigated to in the simulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using android studio emulator, use **CTRL + M and then select Toggle Inspector** [image] a